# how to solve nsusredefaults problem

Tags: iphone

hi i am new to iphone .what i am doing is display 20 images as grid in image.m and display selected image in imageview with image name in imageviewcontoller.h.for displaying lable i am using NSUserDefaults to store tag value of image.what the problem is it displays is previous image name eg: for image 2 displays image 1 name ,for image 3 display image 2 at the first click ,from second click onwords it displays normally how can i solve this pls help me thank u

Comment: Sounds like an indexing problem offhand (where your image 1 should actually be image 0) but would need to see some code to provide any useful info

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `[NSUserDefaults synchronize]` prior to reading your data. Also make sure you are not missing 0th element in the array by mistake.